# Shapefile or GeoJSON?

Tags: python, shapefile, openlayers-2, geojson, pyshp

I'm interested in understanding the relative merits of using GeoJSON or shapefile formats for handling geo-spatial data, particularly in an open-source, Python (CKAN project), web-development context.

GeoJSON is well supported in the CKAN data management python project (through Open Layers), but our clients seem to work with shapefiles.  I'm trying to understand whether I should just ask clients to run their shapefiles through a simple GeoJSON convertor (perhaps even implement this myself upon file upload), or whether there is a good reason to keep their data stored in shpaefile format.

Struggling to find a decent technical comparison of the file formats.  Anyone care to break it down for me?

Comment: It's down to personal (or your IT) preference > a quick highlight is https://feed.terramonitor.com/shapefile-vs-geopackage-vs-geojson/

Comment: both are bad options look at GeoPackage for a well supported standard